# how to pull data automatically from iFace 702 and update it in the database?

Tags: vb.net, database-backups, biometrics

how to pull data automatically from iFace 702 and update it in the database?

i only tried the manual backup. im using vb.net. it is already displaying in my system but i want it to be automatically backup. is there any suggestion for me to do?